# How do I make my submit button display the uploaded file without leaving the current pagte

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

my code is n not working and I am sure its because the code is not 
    correct.I would like to get the submit button to display a picture of a 
    molecule using JSmol.  Any help!??

```
<script>
    var Info = {
    width: 550,
    height: 550,
    serverURL: "http://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jsmol/jsmol.php ",
    use: "HTML5 WEBGL JAVA",
    j2sPath: "jsmol/j2s",
    script: "load 1BNA.pdb; set spin x 15; set spin y 15; set spin z 15; spin on; 
    wireframe on; spacefill off",
    console: "jmolApplet0_infodiv"
     }
</script>




  <form>
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="usr_file" required>
  <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(Info)">
  </form>
  <p id="upload"></p>



<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("Info").required;
document.getElementById("upload").innerHTML = x;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may my answer a little bit off but im using the same logic in my vuejs [component](https://github.com/khofaai/vue-dropify/blob/master/src/Dropify.vue).
in input change event im catching the event so i can get file(s) from it ( onFilesUpload function ).
then im creating image using `FileReader` ( createImage function ) then i push `e.target.result` to my `images` array. then you can set image result to `<img src="image_path" />`